# PHP expect: how to copy contents of the stream

Tags: php, expect

In this example: http://php.net/manual/en/expect.examples-usage.php, i.e.

```
<?php
ini_set("expect.timeout", -1);
ini_set("expect.loguser", "Off");

$stream = expect_popen("ssh root@remotehost");

while (true) {
    switch (expect_expectl ($stream, array (
            array ("password:", PASSWORD), // SSH is asking for password
            array ("yes/no)?", YESNO), // SSH is asking whether to store the host entry
            array ("~$ ", SHELL, EXP_EXACT), // We've got the shell!
    ))) {
        case PASSWORD:
            fwrite ($stream, "secret\n");
            break;
....
```

How would I output the part of $stream that expect_expectl is currently working on?

Probably I haven't completely grasped the concepts and tools to work with streams.

**I want to see each line of the stream regardless if it matches or not** even if that's only for debugging purposes of my script.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [official documentation for `expect_expectl()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.expect-expectl.php), you'll see that it takes a third argument which is populated with the current match. The entire line would be in `$match[0]` and matched segments in the following elements (much like `preg_match()`).

```
while (true) {
    switch (expect_expectl ($stream, array (
            array ("password:", PASSWORD), // SSH is asking for password
            array ("yes/no)?", YESNO), // SSH is asking whether to store the host entry
            array ("~$ ", SHELL, EXP_EXACT), // We've got the shell!
            array (".*", 'ALL', EXP_REGEXP), // Unmatched lines
    ), $match)) {
        case PASSWORD:
            echo $match[0];
            fwrite ($stream, "secret\n");
            break;
        /* other cases */
        case 'ALL':
            echo $match[0];
```

Comment: I want to see each line of the stream regardless if it matches or not.

Comment: Then you can expand the matching items to include all lines (add another rule at the end), and then use the value of `$match[0]` however you like.

Comment: Ok, since they are globs you'd have to match e.g. *password* and not just password otherwise the match[0] buffer would only contain "password". That is one thing. However just putting a wildcard there won't help since it will always go there and never match any other lines.